# php random number generator always running on server

Tags: php, web-services, wordpress

Quick bit of background - I wanted to build this in .net, but my hosting provider will charge $75 to enable .net, and I'm too tight to pay more. So php it is. I'm not super familiar with php, outside of chopping around in wordpress (which is where I'll probably be implementing this).

What I need is a random number generator (this part is easy), sitting on my server and creating a random number every x seconds, provided there is at least one visitor on the site. So essentially having someone land on the page starts the randomiser, with concurrent visitors all being served the same string of numbers. Does that make sense? Maybe I could set a flag when one visitor arrives, that stops subsequent polling?

I'm thinking that I'd achieve the first part by hooking into load(), starting the service and pumping out the numbers, all pretty straight forward. How do I ensure that concurrent visitors do not poll the service, but are served the output generated by visitor one? I've tried to illustrate what I mean below:

```
visitor one hits site - polls service 3 5 23 50 29 11 59 84 99 17 34 55
                            visitor two hits site  11 59 84 99 17 34 55
                                              visitor three 99 17 34 55
```

Hope that makes some sense, any ideas are greatly appreciated...

EDIT: Something like this for a daemon?

```
class TheDaemon
{
    public function run()
    {
        while (1) {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}

$daemon = new TheDaemon();
$daemon->run();
```

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, what are you doing with these numbers?

Comment: A numer generator as a service? Creating a random number every x seconds when there is at least 1 visitor on the site? This probably should be a stand-alone script or function that returns a random number when invoked.

Comment: @Problematic - it's really just a crowdsourcing experiment, for no other reason than a bit of fun. Only if it's not too painful to set up

Answer (score 1):

You need a cron job that runs every x server and that writes your number in a file.

At that point you can just read the file and echo the number to your users. If you need some code tell me

Code for your `cron.php` file

```
$numberToWrite=10;
$numbers=array();
while($numberToWrite--) {
   $numbers[]=rand();
}
file_put_contents('yourfile',implode("\n",$numbers));
```

Now that the cron crated the file with random numbers all you need to do is to read them with:

```
 do {
      $randomNumbers = file('yourfile');
 } while (!isset($randomNumbers[20]));    //> A bit of busy-waiting, anyway not significant
```

Note I am using a do while here to check if the file is not empty and I uset `isset()` because it's 10x faster than `count`ing the entire array.

Comment: @yes123 - I had thought using cron might be the better way - leave it running on the server irrespective of whether the page has been requested, then when it is just serve up the current number. Some code would be great...

Comment: although, a cron wouldn't give the interval I need, unless it triggered a script that runs for say, five minutes, every five minutes.

Comment: The problem with this is that the file write is not necessarily atomic. If a user happens to refresh the page while the cron job is writing to the file, then that user will get a truncated result. Depending on all sorts of factors, that may be vanishingly unlikely, but it’s certainly possible.

Comment: @daniel: no. That cant happen. Try yourself

Comment: rather than grabbing the number from the file, could i do so directly from the cron job? the file is essentially required as a log of the numbers generated and served

Comment: @yes123 I assure you it can. Just because you’ve tried it a few times and it hasn’t happened doesn’t make it impossible. `file_put_contents` is not atomic. Under the hood it will be calling `fopen`, which is also not atomic, and then `fputs` or similar, which **is** usually atomic (if you’re writing less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes). Also, the other process can pre-empt `file_put_contents` between `fopen` and `fputs`, in which case the file will be empty at the time the other process reads it.

Comment: @Daniel: yes I was considering this with the content being way less than PIPE_BUF (he just needs to write few numbers). But acutally I didn't thought about a process being preempted between fopen and fputs. I have added a solution to both your problem see answer. (yes a bit of busy-wait but it's going to be pretty insignificant)

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on your definition of "concurrent".

You could write your string with a timestamp to a text file or a database when the first visitor hits the site and then for every new visitor check that file or the database and the timestamp. If it´s within your time-frame / definition of concurrent, you serve the existing value, if not, you replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Call this the lazy approach, but if you set up a simple database table that has dt and int fields, you could just prepopulate the entire thing.

Then on any given hit, just select the first integer that is associated with a dt >= now().

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a php daemon

read about it here : http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Comment: I've edited my question. How would I run the daemon. Not really familiar with php

Comment: the link that i posted contain the daemon script , it's a script that u run from the command line not from a browser , i didn't personally tried it but what it usually do is wait for an entry and process it